# Problem when importing auto-generated LibGDX gradle project into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I wanted to start learning the LibGDX Framework, and therefore using the Setup app to generate a new project sounded very convenient in the beginning. My problem showed up when i tried to import it as a gradle project into the eclipse IDE. The error message i get is as follows:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Could not run build action
>   using Gradle distribution
>   'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip'.
>   Build file 'E:\Workspace\Eclipse\LibGDX\test\desktop\build.gradle'
>   line: 27 A problem occurred evaluating project ':desktop'. Could not
>   get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput. build.gradle    /test/desktop   line
>   27    Gradle Error Marker

Since I am pretty new to Gradle I dont really now what to do with that.

I have already tried to delete my .grade/wrapper/dist directory and let the LibGDX setup app download it all again. Also the version that was used int the setup app was 4.6 so i tried using that in the import, without success.

When using the gradle version used in the setup app I encountered an other Error message:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Could not create an instance
>   of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution
>   'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip'. Could
>   not create service of type FileMetadataAccessor using
>   NativeServices.createFileMetadataAccessor(). Could not determine java
>   version from '11.0.3'.    test        line 0  Gradle Error Marker

If you need more information, dont hesitate to ask for it, I dont really know what you might need.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I spent 20% of my coding time fighting build issues like this when I was using Eclipse with LibGDX. Now with Android Studio I spend like 2% of my time on it. Eclipse just doesn't have very good support for Gradle projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"classesDir" is deprecated in gradle 5 and replaced with "classesDirs".

If you run into any other issues updating, you may find [this link](https://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=28658) helpful.